# Dynamically cut polygon with css - cross browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a dynamic layout that'll work something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL7JV.jpg

yes, this is just css and html and is working in chrome. What I really would like to do is to reproduce this in every other browser.

What I had in mind was that this white box would be centered, 80% of the screen's width and height. The text overflow would be solved with a scrollbar, I don't really know where that scrollbar would be. I'd like to separate the two elements, leaving an empty space between to allow for some more of that background image to show, but I'm ready to drop that at this point. I can't even make this work in mozilla.

I'm using something like this:

```
.css-shapes-preview { 
width: 60%;
height: 100%;
float: right;
shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 30% 100%);
background-image: url(IMG_0695.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 30% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 30% 100%);
}
```

Which of course is not supported farther than chrome. Is this layout possible or shall I just drop it and think of something simpler?

Code as requested: http://jsfiddle.net/rjz35xs8/1/

Thanks.

Comment: include your full html and css code here

Comment: @Afshin just added a jsfiddle with a simplified version of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get close, but I'm not sure you'll be able to accomplish one key feature.  I don't think there's a cross-browser way of having the text flow within a non-rectangular area.  You can do all of the rest though.

The below example uses the usual trick of different sized borders to make the angled edge and then absolute positioning to place the text on top of the shape.

**EDIT:** After re-reading the question, updated to percentage height as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/a8aqs144/2

```css
body, html{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
#outer{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50/50);
    overflow: hidden;
}
#left{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 45%;
    border-right: 5000px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20000px solid yellow;
}
#content{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 55%;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="left">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed varius consequat imperdiet. Duis eleifend lorem in nunc vestibulum placerat. Phasellus sagittis bibendum est non mattis. Aenean dictum metus vel feugiat eleifend. Maecenas id interdum dolor. Donec in molestie quam, nec commodo justo. Curabitur faucibus faucibus mi a viverra. Curabitur tempus pharetra erat, id interdum eros. Pellentesque at enim ac est feugiat placerat a sit amet risus. Duis a fermentum ante. Phasellus porta non tortor ut molestie. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc scelerisque fermentum risus id venenatis. Quisque nisl justo, tempus sodales nulla scelerisque, hendrerit vestibulum nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you James! Yet it's so sad I can't just wrap it around the edge. The layout just gets ugly with a lot of text so I think I'll just abandon this idea.